# wp_nonce_url to users.php for deleting user not working

Tags: wp-admin, nonce

Using wpjobmanager plugin for my site gojobr.com.au :

I've encountered a problem: to combat spam users that keep posting the same spammy jobs (they are doing so manually so no a captcha won't solve the issue), I wanted to create an easy way to delete a user from the job_listings admin page ( wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=job_listing ).

I entered the following code and the column is appearing correctly on the job_listings page, however the nonce generated is different (and not working) to the wp-core users list admin page's user-delete link (which uses the exact same code as below).
(located at wp-admin/includes/class-wp-users-list-table.php line 372):

// Populate content for this custom column
add_action( 'manage_job_listing_posts_custom_column', 'gjcontent_job_listing_posts_custom_column', 99);

function gjcontent_job_listing_posts_custom_column($column) {
    /* @var $post WP_Post */
    global $post;

```
switch ($column) {

    case 'user_info' :
        if ( empty( $post->post_author) ) {
           echo '&nbsp;';
        } else {
            $del_url = 'users.php?action=delete&user=' . $post->post_author;
            echo '<a href="' . wp_nonce_url($del_url) . '" title="Delete user">Delete</a>'; //nonce not working :-(
        }

    break;

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

[You're not using nonces right](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_url/) - you need to match the nonce action & name that WordPress checks in core for deleting a user. Taken from the source of `WP_Users_List_Table`:

```
wp_nonce_url( "users.php?action=delete&amp;user={$post->post_author}", 'bulk-users' )
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, that worked! Eish bit of a schoolboy error from me not to notice it in the wp core file wiht the 'bulk-users' ... thanks again!